# Set environment variable from inside a windows service

Tags: python, windows, service, environment-variables

I would like to set a environment variable from inside a window service. My first trial was to use the os.environ['flag']='1'. This works from cmd shell but when I put it inside the body of a service it simply do nothing.

Here is a simplified peace of code that create a windows service that just try to change the value of this variable. It try to write '1' to a environment variable called test_flag, sleep for 60 seconds and then writes it back to '0'.
The idea of this is to have some way the procedure inside the service start running and monitor if the flag_test come back to '0' in certain interval (kind of timeout). If not the procedure had hang and I will need to restart the service. I know this is not beautiful but I am running out of ideas (the real problem is asyncio task that hangs without throwing any exception).

I also tried to use the win32api.SetEnvironmentVariable and it also don't work.

```
import threading
import win32api
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event
import os
from time import sleep

class InterruptedException(Exception):
    pass

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,controller):
        self._controller = controller
        self._stop = threading.Event()
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()
        
    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()
        
    def run(self):
        try:
            # Insert the code you want to run as a service here
            # rather than do "execfile(.../.../blah)" simply do:
            # You can have your code throw InterruptedException if your code needs to exit
            # Also check often if self.stopped and then cleanly exit

            os.environ['test_flag']='1'
         
             # initializing classes
            sleep(60)

            os.environ['test_flag']='0'

        # if code in another module is not yours or cannot check often if it should stop then use multiprocessing which will spawn separate processes that you can terminate then from here when you need to stop and return
        # in that case simply block here on self._stop.wait()
        except InterruptedException:
            # We are forcefully quitting 
            pass
        except Exception:
            pass
            # Oh oh, did not anticipate this, better report to Windows or log it
        finally:
           # Close/release any connections, handles, files etc.
           # OK, we can stop now
           win32event.SetEvent(self._controller)

class envvar_service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "py_varenv_test"
    _svc_display_name_ = "ENVVAR test"
    _svc_description_ = "Service test use of os.environ"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)     
        self.hWaitDone = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)        
        
        self.worker = WorkerThread(self.hWaitDone)                


    def SvcStop(self):          
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager      
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, '')) 
        
        self.timeout = 600000     # 60 seconds / 1 minute

        self.worker = WorkerThread(self.hWaitDone)
        self.worker.start()
        self.worker.setDaemon=True

        while True:
            # Wait for service stop signal
            rc = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([self.hWaitStop, self.hWaitDone],False,win32event.INFINITE)
            # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened as part of Windows Service Management
            if rc == 0:
                # Stop signal encountered                    
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(self._svc_name_ + " - STOPPED!")  #For Event Log
                break
    
            if rc == 1:
                # Wait until worker has fully finished
                self.worker = WorkerThread(self.hWaitDone)
                self.worker.setDaemon=True
                self.worker.start()

def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
   return True
   
if __name__ == '__main__':   
   win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)   
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(envvar_service)
```

Comment: An env var is the wrong mechanism for implementing a service heartbeat. For one thing, env vars are not global. Each process has its own set of env vars.

Comment: @Dariva  - DId you get any solution for your problem.

Comment: No. I gave up of this approach. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot change the environ from the service because is another process.
You should use some interprocess communication to tell the main process to set the environment.

The easiest way I think is using `multiprocessing.Queue`.

You create a queue and give the queue as an argument to the service.

The service put data to the queue (`queue.put(data)`)

a thread in the main process read from the queue (`data = queue.read()`) and set the env variable accordingly.

If you want to wait to the variable being set you can use a multiprocessing.Event

See multiprocessing and threading.Thread documentation.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

You have to use Event and Queue class from multiprocessing module, not from threading module!!